# Show me stomping/how to stomp

Tags: grammar

1. Show me how to stomp.
2. Show me stomping.

These two don't seem to mean the same, but when you ask a child to demonstrate stomping, would they be equally used?

Comment: How about show me a stomp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show me how to stomp.

The listener may expect an explanation of "how to stomp", rather than simply a demonstration of stomping. That being said, stomping in particular is such a simple act that you would probably just stomp.

This would be a reasonable thing to say to a child, and it would be reasonable to expect them to just stomp.

> Show me stomping.

This is really a pretty odd phrasing.

At the moment, I can't think of any natural situation where I would say "show me [gerund]" as an imperative asking the listener to perform the action. Maybe someone will come up with one and post it in comments.

This sentence might be used if there's a video of the speaker stomping, and they want the listener to play it.

Instead, I might say:

> Stomp.
>   Stomp for me.
>   Please, stomp.

or maybe even

> Show me *some* stomping.

Comment: Thank you, DCShannon. Are you saying that "show me some stomping" is completly appropriate to repalce "show me how to stomp", but not that "show me stomping"?  And you've also mentioned a video of "speaker" stomping, does defining who is acting have any significance on understanding?

Comment: @JoeKim Yes, I think "show me some stomping" would be appropriate in certain situations. The sentence "show me stomping" makes more sense if the speaker is talking about themselves. In other words, a video of myself in which I am stomping is a video of "me stomping". To play that video would be to "show me stomping".